Prioritize external transitions over internal in Statecharts
I am trying to simulate the behavior of a production line that uses cranes to move racks from one process to another. I want to do this by using the material handling library and at the same time a statechart for the agents type racks to know in which specific process are each of them.
The DES flow describes the crane activity. However the agents only exit the delays blocks ( st1,st2) when a stopDelay() function is called. The reason is that I want to control everything from the statechart.

In the statechart picture it can be observed how I included a timeout internal transition for each state. Once that timeout is finished I am calling the stopDelay function, and the crane is picking up the rack and transporting it to ST2. Then at ST2 I am sending a message to the racks agent saying that the rack arrived and the status should be changed toStage2

The case is that when I am sending this message the status inside the agent does not change and remains the same. My guess is that is due to the internal transition but I am not sure if it's possible to put priorities between transitions ( could not find it ).
Also, feel free to suggest a better way to approach this issue because maybe I am making the problem harder than it actually is.


well, is your agent in a state where the exit transition could be triggered by a msg? i.e. check that you are in "Stage1" when sending the message that would take you out of "Stage1". Use some tracelns to track down where things go south... Are you sure you send the msg to the right agent?... So many things could be wrong, first find the actual root problem here so we can help :)

Also, to understand state transitions, see the execution order: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/statecharts/execution-order.html#execution-order
